# strip away previously called </head> tag

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a custom page template in WordPress and assigned it to a page, i have also included the Wordpress header in the template with "<php get_header(); ?>".

However the custom page template has it's own header which means i now have two headers like this:

```
<head>
.....Header content from WordPress...
</head>
<head>
....header content from custom template.....
</head>
```

I want to strip the closing `"</head>"` tag from WordPress, such that when ditch the opening `"<head>"` from the custom template, i will get this:

```
<head>
.....Header content from WordPress......
....header content from custom template.....
</head>
```

I need a script in JavaScript or PHP that i can add right before the custom template opening `"<head>"` tag to strip away WordPress closing "" tag so that both can appear combined.

Comment: How do you get the other <head> do you use file_get_contents and echo it in there or?? I mean how does it end up being two <head> tags

Comment: it is not part of wordpres framework and has it's own header just like this <head>
....header content from custom template.....
</head>